# How to extract media from TWTRTweet iOS

Tags: ios, twitter

I'm working on an iOS Twitter app. Is anyone know how to extract media, like image, video, from TWTRTweet Class?

I used break point to check the content of TWTRTweet, there's the media content, but I don' t know how to get them.

If you know, please tell me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the same issue, I found a way to access it :

```
[myTWTRTweetInstance valueForKey:@"media"]
```

Hope it will work for you ;)